# Dynamically resize imageview with animation in cocoa mac application in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, animation

I am having a cocoa application for mac in objective c.

I am slightly new to mac application.

In my app, I want to implement growing imageview animation like shown below in the images.

[image: Image1] [image: Image2]

As seen from the screenshots, when my window loads, I have some data to feel as it increases its value.

From 0 to the maximum value.

It should show like its rising from 0 to the values that I have specified.

I have seen lots of circular animations but didn't get much idea from that.

please give me suggestions on this.

Please ignore if mistakes as I am new to mac development.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks fun and pretty quick to implement. Send me your code if you want and I'll show you how I would approach this.

Answer (score 0):

You should create mask and apply it to NSImageView layer object using the only image (one for 100%).

Read following [article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7155) and don't be afraid it's about iOS-development, CoreAnimation is available in Cocoa too.